# chm context sensitive help not working after decompiling and compiling again

Tags: chm

I have a C# application which uses .chm file for context sensitive help. I had to add some more html pages to the existing help. Hence I decompiled it using microsoft HTML help workshop and created a new chm file by compiling the previous set of HHC,HHK,HTML files including the newly added HTML files. 
 Now right page opens whenever F1 is pressed at different windows of the application but I am not getting the contents of the chm file on the left hand side, because of this my application users have no way of exploring the whole help chm file page by page.
 Since this behavior is after changing he .chm file, I believe it has nothing to do with the application code. After reading around I doubt that it is because the .hhp file my project is creating is missing some of the settings. Please help

Comment: I'm not sure I get you right. Did you compile the resulting CHM file using *decompiled* HHP/HHC/HHK files or the *original* ones?

Comment: I compiled the resulting CHM file using decompiled HHC/HHK/HTML files. I did not get HHP file while decompiling.
The newly created file and the old one looks same when they are viewed but behaves differently when used with the application. I suspect it could be because of PPH settings.

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling loses the Alias (.ali) and map (.hh) files and their information.  You may be able to get what you need by analyzing the existing .chm with FAR HTML.  Without a map and alias, though, F1 help won't work.